# open docx file server in client and edit by user

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I use ASP.Net for programing web application and have a number of files on the server.

I want the user to click on the button, open the docx file in server in ms Word client.
and edit text by user in ms Word client and save file (text) in server.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Put the Word documents on a network share, then link to them (`<a href="file://\\server\share\document.docx">Some document</a>`). Users will open them in Word and Word will save them to the same location.

I recommend enabling Volume Shadow Copy on the file server to ensure that you have previous versions of the file in case a user accidentally deletes the file or damages it.

The "proper", Microsoft-sanctioned solution is to deploy SharePoint, at tremendous cost to your organisation. It includes built-in web-based Office apps.

Comment: thx. but i do not download file. i went open this file in msword client and click in save item in msword program and save file in server.

Comment: It seems you don't understand my answer: Word will not "download" the file if it's on a UNC share, it will open it and save it back to the share. The only other solution is to look at WebDAV.

Comment: i use this code: <a href="file:///D:/11.doc">Some document</a>   but no open this file :-(